# select records of date column of value (query executed day + 2 days)

Tags: oracle

[This is the result I was expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbJlP.png)[
I have a table T1 with 2 columns NAME & DT as shown in figure

```
CREATE TABLE T1 ( NAME VARCHAR2(1), DT TIMESTAMP(3) ); 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘A’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-13 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’)); 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘B’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2021-02-14 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’)); 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘C’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2022-03-18 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ( ‘D’ , TO_TIMESTAMP(‘2022-03-19 12:00:00.000000000’, ‘YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF’));
```

After executing above query, data gets populated and I want to select the records in such a way that if I run the query today in particular year, it needs to select the date which has DT value **(sysdate + 2)**.

For example:

I have data in table T1 shown in pic, today's date is **12th feb 2021**...If I run query today, I need to get records having DT value of **14th Feb 2021**. In present year, I will run the query on **12th Feb 2021**, I need to select all the records having DT values of **2021 year** and then select the records having DT of value **14th feb 2021.**

In the same way, if I run the same query on next year let us say, I ran the query on **17th march 2022**, I need to get the records having DT value of **19th March 2022**. In next year, I will run the query on **17th March 2022**, I need to select all the records having DT values of **2022 year** and then select the records having DT value of **19th March 2022**.

I was not getting idea what query I need to write in **WHERE CLAUSE** and query should be same and need to execute same query in all years

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URL0y.png)

Comment: Why do you think the "year" has a meaning separate from the date? A date has the year as its component. If you say "sysdate" plus two days, that will always be in the same year as "sysdate" (except when you are running the query in the last two days of December, in which case "plus two days" works correctly to extend to the beginning of January of the next year). Please clarify.

Comment: Not executing the query in last 2 days of the December. The expectation is I need to select the records in such a way that if I query today, I need to get the records having present year DT values and then select the records having DT values of (query executed day + 2 days)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `SYSDATE`, you will always be able to get values based on the current day. If you need to select from the table based on the date/timezone of the current session, you just need to replace `SYSDATE` with `CURRENT_DATE`.

For me, today is **Feb 11 2021**.

This query will return all rows that have the date **Feb 13 2021**. Tomorrow the query will return all rows that have the date **Feb 14 2021**

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE dt >= TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE) + 2 AND dt < TRUNC (CURRENT_DATE) + 3;
```

This query will return all rows that have the year **2021**. Next year the query will return all rows that have the year **2022**

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE dt >= TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') AND dt < TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR;
```

Comment: If I run query today...first I need to select the records having DT of 2021 year and then select the records having DT value of sysdate + 2..That's what I need

Comment: Just added another query on how to query both cases.

Comment: Can I get both the conditions in one query like selecting executed year records and then select (executed day + 2 days) records    and I need to execute the same query in next coming years also...I just need to add AND between two query right? 
                                                                                                                          
 SELECT *
  FROM t1
 WHERE (dt BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 2 AND TRUNC (SYSDATE) + 3 ) AND (dt BETWEEN TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') AND TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YY') + INTERVAL '1' YEAR); Will this query works fine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are expecting from the query. Both conditions can be added to a single query by using the `OR` clause. They way you are describing it sounds like it needs to be 2 separate queries. Can you share output you are expecting based on the sample data?

Comment: `between` is wrong, because it includes both ends. Especially with the OP's data, where all dates are already truncated: if you select **between** `trunc(sysdate) + 2` and `trunc(sysdate) + 3` you will return rows from **both** dates. In general you should write the condition in full, using >= and < (note the STRICT inequality); or, if you know for sure the dates in the table are truncated, simply use equality.

Comment: Nice catch. Thanks mathguy. I've updated the queries.

Comment: @Johnbsdk10, As mathguy suggested, explicit >= and < should be used instead of between. You can combine the two conditions using `AND`, but the query will not return any information on December 30 and 31.

Comment: What if I run the query on 30th Dec 2021 and I need to get the records having DT value of 1st Jan 2022. Will above query works? If not, what is the query I need to use it for this type of scenarios

Comment: What do you expect to be returned by the query if it is run on Dec 30th? Jan 1st 2022 are 2 days ahead, but not the same year (2021).

Comment: okay...Got it...Thanks for the effort to both of them..